# ¿Como hacer que un programa propio se instale en el sistema operativo?

Tags: python, c++, windows, instalacion

la pregunta es, si yo creo un programa simple o aplicacion por ejemplo en python o c++. ¿Como se hace que un programa de esos se instale en el sistema como por ejemplo cuando instalamos winrar, que luego lo podemos ver desde panel de control y desinstalarlo o por poner otro ejemplo, cuando instalamos un juego, tambien lo podemos ver desde el panel de control?

¿Osea, que hace falta para crear esa instalacion de un determinado script o programa?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Creo que WinRar tiene una forma de crear instaladores

Comment: Te refieres a que una vez tenga programaX.py,  desde Winrar quizas sea posible hacer un instalable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale ya lo he resuelto yo mismo, si os interesa como hacer vuestros propios ejecutables para instalarlos en el sistema, de forma que aparezca el recuadro de la licencia, elegir idioma de instalación, la ruta de donde estara la carpeta del programa, etc... y luego incluso poder desinstalar vuestro script desde el panel de control. Para eso teneis que descargar el programa Inno Setup (hay otros, yo personalmente lo hice con este), y una vez instalado, elegimos el script/programa o lo añadimos al panel y seguimos los pasos que nos marca.
Dejo aqui el link a youtube para alaracion. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3F0YnGlTWac

Answer (score 0):

Para Python puedes usar librerías como Pyinstaller o Pynsist.
Para lo que pides seria mejor usar Pynsist ya que genera un instalador usando NSIS: Nullsoft Scriptable Install System